# Format date for SQLite and subtract minutes

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime, calendar

I need to subtract an X number of minutes from the current date and format it for a SQLlite query in my Android app.  This is what I have so far:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -60); //one hour back

final SimpleDateFormat std = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm");
std.setCalendar(cal);           
String date = std.format(cal.getTime());

String sql = "SELECT * FROM [tbl_name] WHERE [datefield] >= " + date;
```

datefield is stored as a DATETIME in the SQLlite table.  I don't want to use Joda time because I want to keep the number of dependencies in my app to a minimum.

With my current code, the date date variable is coming out as: '2012-43-05 07:43'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using minutes twice in your format.  `mm` actually needs to be `MM` in the date portion.

```
final SimpleDateFormat std = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
```